# Problems deploing WildFly on Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jar, wildfly

When I try deploy a Project in **Eclipse Mars** using **WildFly 9.0.2** the *.jar* files are turning *Folder files*.
When I try access the **URL** by browser the server log are showing normally without errors but in browser nothing is showing.
I'm try use **JAVA 6, 7 and 8**, but I have the same problem.

[image]

First file is a package of my project, the second one is a dependency from package

[image]

This is what my browser show me as response when I access *localhost:8080/myApp/*

Someone know what is this?

Comment: you should deploy war to your server instead of jar files.

Comment: the jar files are into the war build by eclipse